# Processing rgb images

Tags: drake

I am using Drake to implement a visual servoing scheme. For that I need to process color images and extract features.

I am using the *ManipulationStation class*, and I have already published the color images of the `rgbd_sensor` objects to LCM channels (in c++). Now I want to process the images during the simulation.
I know that it would be best to process images internally (without using the ImageWriter), and for that, I cannot use the `image_array_t` on LCM channels or `ImageRgbaU8`, I have to convert images to an *Eigen* or *OpenCV* type.

I will then use feature extraction functions in these libraries. These features will be used in a control law.

Do you have any examples on how to write a system or code in c++ that could convert my *Drake images* to *OpenCV* or *Eigen* types? What is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Arnaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no current example converting the `drake::Image` to Eigen or OpenCV but it should be pretty straightforward.

What you should do is create a system akin to `ImageWriter`. It takes an image as an input and does whatever processing you need on the image. You connect its input port to the `RgbdSensor`'s output port (again, like `ImageWriter`.) The only difference, instead of taking the image and converting it to an lcm data type, you convert it to your OpenCV or Eigen type and apply your logic to that.

If you look, `ImageWriter` [declares a periodic publish event](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/systems/sensors/image_writer.cc#L149-L154). Change that to (probably) a discrete update event (still periodic, I'd imagine) and then change [`ImageWriter::WriteImage`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/systems/sensors/image_writer.cc#L161-L162) callback into your "Image-to-OpenCV" callback.

Finally, you could also declare an output port that would make your converted image to other systems.